# accessing two tables from a database for one login page

Tags: cakephp, authentication

Hi I'm trying to create a login page that caters from regular users, admin and then authorities.

The first bit, i.e. admins and regular users login is done, redirecting them to their respective pages upon logging in, but since authorities have a different structure compared to regular users they needed their own table and thus I am stuck as to how I can incorporate their table in the same code that regular users and admins use to login.

Is there anyway of using two tables for one login page?

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
public function login(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $userType = $this->Auth->user('role');
            switch ($userType){

                case "admin":
                    $this->redirect(array("controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"admin"));
                    break;

                case "regular":
                    $this->redirect(array("controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"regular"));
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            echo "Login Failed";
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this plugin which allows multi-column login.
https://github.com/ceeram/Authenticate

Comment: DavidYell - that solution is for mutlicolumn coding but my problem is for multitable coding